# JQuery width() method returning incorrect values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My website uses lazy loading, and I coded a bit of Javascript to keep groups of images at the same aspect ratio, regardless of the user's viewport.

The lazy loading library requires that the src attribute of the images contains a light image like in the example below: a 1 by 1 pixel transparent GIF.

```
<div class="image-art composition">
    <img class="lazyload" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" data-src="art/game/StanleyParable.jpg" width="264" height="264" />
    <img class="lazyload" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" data-src="art/game/TheBeginnersGuide.jpg" width="461" height="264" />
</div>
```

Now the problem is that on `$(document).ready`, this function is called:

```
function getOriginalImageSizes() {
  $(".image-art img").each(function(index) {
    originalImageSizes[index] = {
      width: $(this).width(),
      height: $(this).height()
    };
  });
}
```

And for some obscure reason, sometimes my images return a 1x1 size, and sometimes their real size that is specified in their `width`/`height` attribute.

The big issue is that then, my rescaling javascript code resizes the images according to this 1-pixel size, which makes it so that then the lazyloading library loads the images into those tiny `<img>` elements instead of displaying them in their real size.

Does anyone have any idea why `$(this).width()` returns the width of the content of `src` instead of the width of the `<img>` element? According to the documentation here: https://api.jquery.com/width/ it seems like my code should work fine.

Comment: I think the problem might be that the code is sometimes running before the images are fully loaded? Maybe if you try running the code inside of `$(window).on('load', function(){...});` it should wait until all page elements have loaded

Comment: @sbrass .load() was previously deprecated and now removed in jQuery >= 3.0

Comment: Oh sorry, then maybe `window.onload=function(){...};`

Comment: Width and height attributes are present on the image tags, so this is unlikely to be a load order problem; `width()` and `height()` will return those values even if the image is broken or missing. @NorahJones   Are you certain your "rescaling javascript code" isn't causing this problem in the first place?   Is it possibly running before `originalImageSizes` is filled by the function above?

Comment: Unless javascript defaults values at 1 instead of 0, it's unlikely. When running it with a ratio of 0.68, the images are resized to 0.68 pixels.

I also tried waiting 10 seconds before calling getOriginalImages and you're right, it still gets a 1px value instead of the real size of the images.

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out... I forgot a `width`/`height`: `auto` in the CSS! Sorry for the trouble